# Create JavaScript Array From MSSQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am attempting to create a JavaScript array from a MSSQL query results.  Below is my syntax that I attempt to use, but the array is not created.  How should this be set-up so that the JavaScript array is properly assigned?

```
<?php 
    $mssql = new mssql("localhost", "user", "password", "testdb");
    $data=mssql_query($mssql,"SELECT * FROM test");
?>
<script>
    var firstNames=[<?php 
        while($info=mssql_fetch_array($data))
            echo $info['f_name'].','; 
?>];
<?php
    $data=mssql_query($mssql,"SELECT * FROM test");
?>
var lastNames=[<?php 
        while($info=myssql_fetch_array($data))
            echo '"'.$info['l_name'].'",'; 
?>];
</script>
<?php
    $mysqli->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Is it MSSQL or MySQL or MySQLi? You appear to be using all three APIs

Comment: FYI - the mysql commands are deprecated. Switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: In any case, fetch all data into a PHP array, then use `var firstNames = <?= json_encode($phpArray) ?>`

Comment: @Phil - It is MSSQL

Comment: You really need to clean up your code then. `myssql_fetch_array` is not even a function and `$mysqli` is not defined

Comment: @Phil - thank you for those notes.  I will work on cleaning up my code to be better syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

A good approach here would be to get the query (after correcting the deficiencies in the code as noted below your post, then casting the whole array to JSON using `json_encode($data);` and then `echo $data` in to your javascript.

This is not the only way to do it. I'm sure others will suggest other things.

Comment: How would I echo $data into my javascript?

Comment: for example:

<script>
var test = <?php echo $datda; ?>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

I know, W3 Schools isn't the best, but it's okay.

You can do that with jQuery easy, just google a bit and you need php knowledge for creating an array out of a mysql query.